# changing url displayed to user in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I don't know if this is strange request or not, but I have a page with users profiles displaying. Each user has unique username of course and those are included in links to associated with their names. when clicked it goes to their profile:

```
profile/profile_guest/username
```

When the user clicks on one of the profiles, it goes to user's profile and url in the address bar is:

```
http://domain.com/profile/profile_guest/ahlam
```

What I want to achieve is to configure routes.php to handle this. so once clicked, it goes to profile page but what shows in URL address bar is :

```
domain.com/ahlam
```

To do that, I tried :

```
$route['someTest'] = "profile/profile_guest/$1";
```

Fair to say that it didn't work and still the whole URL displayed. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like

```
$route['sometest/(:any)'] = "your/link/$1";
```

The '$1' is like a parameter you gonna receive from the '(:any)' part.

Comment: I do not understand...can you please explain?

Comment: almost. problem with the OP request is using the base as a catch all. So it would be $route['(:any)'] = "profile/profile_guest/$1"; which will almost positively cause problems elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
//site.com/john          = "profile/profile_gest/john"
$route['([a-z0-9\-_]+)'] = "profile/profile_gest/$1";
//where $1 = "john", so "john" respects the pattern set below
```

But CI Routing will understand any URI match this pattern like "index", "post", ... is a routing for the profile controller.

TO prevent that you can add a specification to the url, for examples:

```
//site.com/john.html
$route['([a-z0-9\-_]+)\.html'] = "profile/profile_gest/$1";

//site.com/user-john
$route['user\-([a-z0-9\-_]+)'] = "profile/profile_gest/$1";
```

Or

> if you are sure that any usernames will not contest with an another pages
>   always put this rules at the bottom, in order to that CI will check all other routing rules before this one.

Note: Before that your [htaccess](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/)  have to be set to remove index.php from your urls.

[CI URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

[Regular expression](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)