# How can I redirect every pages, when I login every user's account. I want them to redirect to their respective pages(codeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I redirect every user page when I login their credentials in codeigniter

Comment: Please provide us with the piece of code you are having trouble with so the community can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Read this for user redirect based on role: 
[redirect to admin and user based on user role in code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600227/redirect-to-admin-and-user-based-on-user-role-in-code-igniter).

You can either redirect normal users to redirect('users/dashboard', 'refresh') 
or if you the url to be specific for each users. Read this
[changing url displayed to user in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152441/changing-url-displayed-to-user-in-codeigniter)